# Type aliases in C++

Tags: c++

I have a class `Point` and a class `Rect`. I want to have two constructors for the `Rect`: One with a `Point` and a dimension (width, height) and one with two Points (top left, bottom right). Now it turns out that `Point` also can be seen as a dimension, so instead of creating a `Dimension` class I want to use my `Point`, basically like this:

```
class Point{...};
typedef Dimension Point;

class Rect{
    public:
        Rect(Point, Point);
        Rect(Point, Dimension);
}
```

So the question is: Does the compiler make a difference between `Point` and `Dimension`?  I tried it, the message ist "call of overloaded Rect(Point, Point) is ambiguous.".

How should I do that? Preferably without inheritance :)

**EDIT**

I understood now that it's the same to the compiler. But there is another scenario wher I need that.

I have a Point. The coordinates can be in a carthesian system (x, y) or GPS coordinates (lon, lat). It's perfectly ok for me to call the components `x0` and `x1` so I want to use only one class.

Now I want to calculate the distance between the two points and my idea is as follows:

```
typedef PointLonLat Point;
typedef PointXY Point;

double distance(PointLonLat, PointLonLat);
double distance(PointXY, PointXY);

PointLonLat p1(10, 10);
PointLonLat p2(11, 11);

double dist = distance(p1, p2); // the correct implementation is used
```

I know it doesn't work like that. But would the answer to that also be "make two classes"?

Comment: Point and dimension are same to the compiler.Why would you need two declarations?

Comment: @bashrc: Presumably because initialization differs for the two cases (you can specify a rectangle using two points, or one point and it's dimensions - the calculations are different for these two cases).

Comment: so why typedef Point to Dimension?Another class should be added for Dimension then?
From design point of view both appear to be different to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `point` and `dimension` don't have identical behaviour, then your `typedef` is a logic error. If they do, then you don't need two constructors.

---

*In response to your edit*

For the example you've provided, what you have is two classes that store the same amount of data but have different behaviour. It's analagous to `std::size_t` and `void*` - they're both the same number of bits to the underlying hardware, but the language's type system gives them totally different meanings.

Your example could be solved by using two different classes, or by using a template class to avoid duplication like this:

```
enum CoordinateSystem {
  Geographic,
  Cartesian
};

template<CoordinateSystem C>
struct Point {
  double x,y;
};

double distance(Point<Cartesian>, Point<Cartesian>);
double distance(Point<Geographic>, Point<Geographic>);
```

Answer (score 3):

All typedefs are same for compiler.

You could do this instead:

```
//class template to be used to generate different class types!
template<int>
class Type{ /*...*/ };

//instantiate different class types, each with different template argument
typedef Type<0> Point;
typedef Type<1> Dimension;
typedef Type<2> Size;

class Rect{
    public:
        Rect(Point, Point);
        Rect(Point, Dimension); //its a different constructor!
};
```

Using this approach, you create different types out of the class template `Type`.

---

Instead of integer literals, you could use *named* enum as:

```
enum TypeArg
{
    PointArg,
    DimensionArg,
    SizeArg
};

template<TypeArg>
class Type{ /*...*/ };

typedef Type<PointArg>     Point;
typedef Type<DimensionArg> Dimension;
typedef Type<SizeArg>      Size;
```

---

Or even better use empty classes as:

```
//empty classes
struct PointArg{};
struct DimensionArg{};
struct SizeArg{};

template<typename T>
class Type{ /*...*/ };

typedef Type<PointArg>     Point;
typedef Type<DimensionArg> Dimension;
typedef Type<SizeArg>      Size;
```

This last approach is adopted by many C++ libraries, such as Boost.

Comment: Nice trick.  Can also be used for Time and TimeDiff and the likes.  Similar to boost::multi_index_container, I would even suggest making empty classes instead of numbers to make a more documented distinction (class PointType {}; class DimensionType {};)

Comment: @stefaanv: Using empty classes is a nice idea.

Comment: I think it looks horrible and surely Dimension and Point objects will have different member functions anyway and won't share much if anything in implementation. IMO much simpler to have two different classes; simpler to implement and simpler to understand.

Comment: @ChrisCard: If `Dimension` and `Point` has different member functions, then the OP wouldn't have tried using `typedef` which doesn't create different types. So my solution particular solves that problem.

Comment: @ChrisCard : ... Also, in case you have different members for both types, in addition to some common members, then you could do this : `class Point : public Type<PointArg> { /* ...*/ };` and similarly for the `Dimension`.  In this way, you've different types, without common base which provides type-safety.

Comment: yes, but I think they *should* have different member functions and that the idea of trying to make Point and Dimension the same is broken. Also, I don't see what you gain using the templated approach, except more conceptual complexity.

Answer (score 2):

You should make `Dimension` a different type. Yes, a `Point` can be used to specify a dimension, but it doesn't mean that it makes sense to use the same type.

Comment: JesperE, so you recommend making a class or struct Dimension?

Comment: @wal-o-mat: depends. Dimension in the sense of Size? If that then yes, wholeheartedly. Making a distinction incurs some extra code, but in my experience there's much less room for errors in the client code. I would even make sure to use different data members (like w and h, as Didier suggests), and of course no implicit conversion between point and size.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler makes no difference between `Point` and `Dimension`.

You have to create another class for `Dimension`. Just as a hint, you can use `w` and `h` instead of `x` and `y` for its members.

Answer (score 0):

One quick solutions is that you can have one constructor and figure out the class that is being provided inside it's logic

Answer (score 0):

Although Dimension and Point are similar in that they can both be implemented as a pair of numbers, their behaviour isn't the same, e.g. Dimension would probably have member functions like height() and width() whereas Point might have x() and y(). So you shouldn't make them the same, but have different classes for each.

Answer (score 0):

You can try making Dimension inherit from Point Instead of be a typedef:
`class Dimension : public Point {}`
Also, it is inefficient to pass the object types as copies; pass them as constant references instead.  That has the additional benefit of allowing the compiler to generate polymorphic code for those types.

Comment: That's hilarious. Copying a Point class, which is probably at most 8 bytes, compared to virtual functions? The overhead of copying such a class is trivial.

Comment: What about as time goes on and the types are augmented?  It would be a laborious task to change the code later after it was discovered that copies were a bottleneck.